# Add a data-src in addiction to src to all of my images to improve a lazy load function in a WordPress environment

Tags: javascript, wordpress, lazy-loading

My problem is that I want to implement a system of lazy load on my website.

I'm using a framework called unveil.js but the problem is that it requires a data-src added to src to every image.

So essentially, I need to add to every image a duplicate of the src attribute (for example src="image1.jpg") and wrap it inside the data-src.

Something like that:

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var datasrc = this.attr("src");
    //somthing else to add the data-src
});
```

This is something advance for me, but I want to implement this script on my website. I tried a couple of plugins, but they don't do what I'm looking for because essentially my problem is that all of my images lives outside the theme folder on wordpress (or the plugin folder) so it was impossible for me to call them in that way. Thanks

Comment: By the time you're changing the src attribute to a data-src, some or all of your images might already have been loaded, which defies all reason to implement lazy loading in the first place. That's definitely a task for the server-side!

Comment: you're probably right..

Comment: He could do it via javascript and load it render blocking so the page doesn't load until it's loaded the JS?

Comment: you mean onload?

Comment: JavaScript in the head of a WordPress site is known as render blocking so it loads before the rest of the page

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about the same.. I'm not sure it would be the right approach though because I'm building this system in order to avoid render blocking script and improve my mark on google, but I guess that I don't have a choice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Javascript/jQuery as follows:

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var datasrc = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).attr("datasrc", datasrc);
});
```

Ensure you load the script in the head to make it render blocking so your page doesn't load until the script has been loaded.